# Get if following a page

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying get if user is following a page, but return empty...

In relationship return empty:

```
public function get_following()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Followers::class, 'user_id')->where('type', '=', 0)->where('follower_id', '=', auth()->user()->id);
}
```

dd($user);

```
UserProfile {#301 ▼
  #table: "users_profile"
  #relations: array:3 [▼
    "user" => User {#305 ▶}
    "shares" => Collection {#307 ▶}
    "get_following" => null
  ]
```

This code return result:

```
$get_follow = Followers::where('type', '=', 0)->where('follower_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->where('user_id', '=', 1)->first();

dd($get_follow);
```

Return:

```
Followers {#329 ▼
  #attributes: array:4 [▼
    "id" => 22
    "user_id" => 1
    "follower_id" => 1
    "type" => 0
  ]
```

Comment: are you use 2 foreign key in your relation??  `user_id `, `follower_id` ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try ro name the relations better, it helps you to have a better undrastanding of subject

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
   public function user()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }

   public function followers()
   {
     return $this->user()->followers();
   }
}

class User extends Model
{   

   Public function followers()
   {
     return $this hasMany(Follower::class);
   }
}

Class Follower extends Model
{
  public function user()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

**Now how do you get followers from a peofile ?**

`$profile->followers`